# Taking a screenshot of uploaded files using Python/Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

There are design files uploaded/downloaded by users on a website. For every uploaded file, I would like to show a screenshot of the file so people can see an image before they download them.

They are very esoteric files though that need to be opened in particular design tools. (I even don't have the software to run them on my local machine).

My thinking is that I can run a virtual machine that has these programs installed, programmatically open the files, and then take a screenshot of the opened file and save a thumbnail. But I want to do this when the user uploads the design file.

But someone told me PIL could do this. But I investigated and can't seem to figure out any documentation on how to go about this.

Has anyone ever done something like this before? What is the best approach?

Comment: [http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm)?

Comment: Ok, I assumed that your "particular design tools" were Windows programs, and that the virtual machine was running Windows (I'm no Heroku expert...).

Comment: Yes they are Windows programs actually -- but I use a Mac... But will that program work then work with a Windows-based program regardless of the OS you run it on? Sorry it's me that's the ignorant noob. In reality, the Heroku aspect is probably irrelevant

Comment: If you want to take a screen shot of a Windows program, you will need to run Windows. I assume that your uploaded data is not just pictures (which you could paste into a screen shot of your program  to fake a screen shot with the data). Can't you just give your users the possibility to also upload a screen shot together with the data?

Comment: Yeah but I wanted a nicer user experience where the screenshot magically appears. But I guess I could look into running a Windows VM to do all of this.